# Need help manipulating directory string in a function

Tags: r, path

I'm having trouble getting the current the current directory of my R Shiny app. I use the `getSrcDirectory` function to get the script's current directory and then try to manually modify it into the appropriate format to pass to `xlsx::loadWorkbook`, in order to load a .xlsx file. Here is the pertinent code:

```
#get the directory of the script by creating an empty function. 
src<-getSrcDirectory(function(x) {x})

wb <- loadWorkbook(file = c(gsub("/", "\\\\", c(src, "/www/NJ2012.xlsx")),
                            "\\www\\NJ2012.xlsx"))
```

I'm trying to get the file directory to look like this: `C:\\Users\\misha\\Desktop\\Accessible Project\\R_Econ_App\\www\\NJ2012.xlsx`.

My script is in a folder called `R_Econ_App`, so it should be included in the `src` variable. I concatenated an additional string to the src string to provide some more information about where certain files are in certain sub directories. I use `gsub` in an attempt to replace "/" with "\" because that's what the file directory passed into `loadWorkbook` has to look like.

Can you please help me figure out where my mistake is and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't bother with `gsub`. Just use `file.path` to join your directory and file path

```
loadWorkbook(file=file.path(src, "www", "NJ2012.xlsx"))
```